# On kittinunf/fuel unable to revert answer body when http status < 200 || > 299

Tags: android, http, https, fuel

I'm using [kittinunf/fuel](https://github.com/kittinunf/fuel) to build up an app under Android.

Referring to the first example on documentation that I paste here:

```
import com.github.kittinunf.fuel.httpGet
import com.github.kittinunf.result.Result;
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val httpAsync = "https://httpbin.org/get"
        .httpGet()
        .responseString { request, response, result ->
            when (result) {
                is Result.Failure -> {
                    val ex = result.getException()
                    println(ex)
                }
                is Result.Success -> {
                    val data = result.get()
                    println(data)
                }
            }
        }
    httpAsync.join()
}
```

It's possible to revert the http message body with `val data = result.get()` also in case of an http status < 200 or > 299? Servers will often return extended error status message in the body and this is fully supported in iOS http stack.

Answer (score 0):

In case of an error - following the example above - when result is **Result.Failure** `response.body()` contains the answer payload (identical as `result.get()` in case of **Result.Success**).